# php force download headers

Tags: php, download, http-headers, media

Which headers are most important to force a download and which headers get auto filled by the browsers

For e.g.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: '.sprintf("%u", filesize($zip_out)));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zip_out).'"');
```

I omit all the headers except line 1 and 2, download is working fine why/how ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Content-Disposition: attachment` tells your browser the content is an attachment. So the browser will start to download the content as a file.

According to [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.2):

> If the disposition type matches "attachment" (case-insensitively),
> this indicates that the recipient should prompt the user to save the
> response locally, rather than process it normally (as per its media
> type).

`Content-type: application/zip` says your browser that the content is zipped, and usually makes the browser to download the content as a file, even if `Content-Disposition: attachment` is omitted, because that is the default behavior of the browser for zipped content.

I have never seen `Content-Description` header in any of HTTP-related specifications and I think it does not affect download at all.